# how to add columns side by side in sql server by using select query

Tags: sql-server

i want to show the select query output in a columns side by side. currently im showing in one column in multiple records.

code

```
select sum(Fan1Hrs) as Fan1Hrs from (select CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp) as Date, max(Convert(int, Fan1Hrs)) as Fan1Hrs from RawData where MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) group by CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp))comp1
union all
select sum(Fan2Hrs) as Fan2Hrs from (select CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp) as Date, max(Convert(int, Fan2Hrs)) as Fan2Hrs from RawData where MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) group by CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp))comp2
union all
select sum(Fan3Hrs) as Fan3Hrs from (select CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp) as Date, max(Convert(int, Fan3Hrs)) as Fan3Hrs from RawData where MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) group by CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp))comp3


Exp Op:
FAN1Hrs  FAN2Hrs  FAN3Hrs
1234     1123     2323
```

Current OP

```
FAN1Hrs
    1234
    1123
    2323
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
with fan_cte as (
    select CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp) as Date, 
             max(Convert(int, Fan1Hrs)) as Fan1Hrs,
             max(Convert(int, Fan2Hrs)) as Fan2Hrs,
             max(Convert(int, Fan3Hrs)) as Fan3Hrs
    from RawData
    where MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) 
          AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())) 
    group by CONVERT(Date, devicetimestamp))
select sum(Fan1Hrs) as Fan1Hrs, sum(Fan2Hrs) as Fan2Hrs, sum(Fan3Hrs) as Fan3Hrs
from fan_cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

SteveC's answer may very well be superior, but I wanted to offer an alternative.

Since you are only returning one value due to the MAX() function I don't think you need to SUM() as well. Also the usage of MAX() will ensure only one value per subquery. Given that we can use a CROSS JOIN to give you the side by side results. This will do a Cartesian product (all combinations of all rows), but this won't be a problem since each subquery will only have one row.

```
SELECT
           comp1.Fan1Hrs
         , comp2.Fan2Hrs
         , comp3.Fan3Hrs
FROM       (
               SELECT
                        CONVERT(DATE, devicetimestamp) AS Date
                      , MAX(CONVERT(INT, Fan1Hrs))     AS Fan1Hrs
               FROM     RawData
               WHERE    MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
                    AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp)  = YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
               GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, devicetimestamp)
           ) comp1
CROSS JOIN (
               SELECT
                        CONVERT(DATE, devicetimestamp) AS Date
                      , MAX(CONVERT(INT, Fan2Hrs))     AS Fan2Hrs
               FROM     RawData
               WHERE    MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
                    AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp)  = YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
               GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, devicetimestamp)
           ) comp2
CROSS JOIN (
               SELECT
                        CONVERT(DATE, devicetimestamp) AS Date
                      , MAX(CONVERT(INT, Fan3Hrs))     AS Fan3Hrs
               FROM     RawData
               WHERE    MONTH(DeviceTimeStamp) = MONTH(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
                    AND YEAR(DeviceTimeStamp)  = YEAR(DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()))
               GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, devicetimestamp)
           ) comp3;
```